# Android classloader for optimized dex (odex) files

Tags: android, classloader, dexclassloader

I am attempting to find a class loader that works for optimized dex files (odex files).  I looked through all the android documentation and found the following class loaders.

- DexClassLoader
  https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html
- PathClassLoader
  https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/PathClassLoader.html
- UrlClassLoader
  https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLClassLoader.html

They all seem to work for either APKs or JAR files (or APKs that contain classes.dex files), but none seem to work for odex files :(

I have an optimized dex file that I would like to load into my app but I am struggling to find a way to load the file.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: how are you creating `DexClassLoader` ?

Comment: I tried doing this: new DexClassLoader(pathToResourceOnlyApk, pathToOdexFile, null, getClassLoader()); where that last argument is the class loader of my current context.  When I do this, since the resourceOnly APK does not have classes.dex, it does not allow me to create the DexClassLoader.

Comment: post your code in your question

Comment: Sorry about that :) I pushed enter to put a new line but I guess it auto posts :)